# SQL - Linked List Table - Is there a better way to write this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table in Windows SQL Server that functions similarly to a linked list - each row might be the first node of a new list, or the next node in an existing list. So the table has a NodeId (it's Primary Key) and a PreviousNodeId (The ID of the prior node in the list, or NULL if it's the first node in the list).

Sample code - "A" through "E" are linked, "F" through "H" are linked, and "I" is not linked to anything.

```
DECLARE @Nodes TABLE (NodeId CHAR PRIMARY KEY, PreviousNodeId CHAR)

INSERT INTO @Nodes VALUES
('A', NULL),
('B', 'A'),
('C', 'B'),
('D', 'C'),
('E', 'D'),
('F', NULL),
('G', 'F'),
('H', 'G'),
('I', NULL)
```

I need to write code to display each node in the table, as well as the oldest node in it's list. So for the table above, that would be:

[image: FinalResults]

I have achieved this with the following code...

```
DECLARE @FinalResults TABLE (CurrentNodeId CHAR, OldestNodeId CHAR)
DECLARE @ThisNode CHAR

DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
(SELECT NodeId FROM @Nodes)

OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
INTO @ThisNode  --This is the node we are going to create an entry for

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @OldestKnownNode CHAR = @ThisNode   --Start by assuming that we are currently looking at the oldest node
    DECLARE @PreviousNode CHAR = '!'            --Need something to make it not null on the first pass

    --Run this loop for our node to see if it has a previous node.
    --If so, set that node as our oldest known node and run again to see if that has a previous node, etc.
    WHILE @PreviousNode IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @PreviousNode = (
        SELECT r.PreviousNodeId FROM @Nodes r
        WHERE r.NodeId = @OldestKnownNode)

        IF (@PreviousNode IS NOT NULL) SET @OldestKnownNode = @PreviousNode
    END

    INSERT INTO @FinalResults VALUES (@ThisNode, @OldestKnownNode)


    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
    INTO @ThisNode
END
CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor
```

...but I am worried that this will cause performance issues on a larger table. Is there a way to write this without the CURSOR and WHILE loop, so that I'm not hitting the table repeatedly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select nodeid, nodeid as oldestnodeid
      from nodes
      where previousnodeid is null
      union all
      select n.nodeid, cte.oldestnodeid
      from cte join
           nodes n
           on cte.nodeid = n.previousnodeid
     )
select *
from cte
order by nodeid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0996da5e3aa8aa134fe40b3d1d0f1243) is a db<>fiddle.

Although this is also "iterative", it is much better than the cursor-based approach.  Basically, all three "oldest" nodes are handled in parallel.  So the query recurses 5 times -- for the As -- rather iteratively looping through 9 rows.